# Redesign database to allow for per-user alterations of default objects

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database design that stores options for multiple projects globally, boss man now wants the ability to specify the category weight on a per project bases.

This is my current database design....

```
Category (grouping of items)
-name
-weight

Item (a task that needs completed for objects)
-name
-id_category
-order_by
-(other info here)

Project
-name
-(lots of other stuff)

ProjectItems
-id_item
-id_project
-status (enum - not complete, in progress, complete)
```

Measures are grouped into categories, which have their own weights used in the calculation of percentage complete (how many items are completed vs total number of items for a project.. some categories are more complex than others, so when items from a certain category are finished, they should make the percentage complete jump relatively).

This model currently works really well, every project that is created gets object items populated based on user selection from a submitted form.

What would be the best way to re-design the database to support per-project category weights just for boss man?

Notes: The categories should not need to ever change, just the weights.

Answer (score 1):

Add a single column, catWeight, to your Item table of the same type as the weight column in the Catagory table. When a new item is created for a project set the column to the value in the catagory table. Allow the user to modify the value in the catWeight column.

Comment: This supposes Item records are unique to a given Project. Absent more information, ProjectItems implies that the Item table is shared across projects. So this won't work if that's the case.

Comment: Right, items are shared between projects. What I am lacking is a place to actually put a specific user altered category weight for each project, unless I made another table called "ProjectsCategories", and then add an id_project_category to "ProjectItems". This just seems a hacky way of implementation.